# Matlab: Using 'dlmwrite' in a Loop

Tags: matlab

Suppose that a `dlmwrite` command has been used as follows (`period` is a vector):

```
period=[10;20;30;40;50;60;70];
dlmwrite('Parameters.tcl',['set Tn {',num2str(period(n)),'}',''],'delimiter','','-append');
```

The output of above code for n=1, writes the below text in 'Parameters.tcl':

```
set Tn {10}
```

Now, I want use `dlmwrite` in a loop. For example if n=2, I wand the output should be:

```
set Tn {10 20}
```

If n=3:

```
set Tn {10 20 30}
```

And so on. How do I do?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following fragment:

```
num2str(period(n))
```

with the following:

```
strjoin(cellstr(num2str(period(1:n))), ' ')
```